# Can't call function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am only just getting a hang of bits of Jquery:

I have this code (that won't work in fiddle for some reason whatsoever), that i half made myself but got most of it from another fine person:

```
<script>
$('button#test').click(function(){
    var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();
    $('div#videocontainer').html($(videos));
});
</script>
```

I am using it to put a bunch of iframe videos into one div, because when they are made (by a program i created), they are all put into a seperate "videoframe" div, as you can imagine by looking at the code i inserted.
This makes it very annoying to style it in CSS, been fighting with it for some days now..

**Issue:**

The function is working, it does indeed put all the .videoframe divs and everything inside, into the #videocontainer div. BUT I can't get the function called, unless i use .click, i want the function to be called (only one time if possible) when a user loads the page, something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();
    $('div#videocontainer').html($(videos));
});
</script>
```

However that is not working either.

Anyone here that know how to fix it/what's wrong? If not - maybe a different way to put the videos into the div, they come from this script:

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=mxHB21dKmkw&key=[you are not getting my key :)]', function(data){
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=mxHB21dKmkw&key=[you are not getting my key :)]', function(data2){
        {$('body').append('<div class = videoframe><iframe src=https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k allowfullscreen = allowfullscreen class = video></iframe><div class = counter>'+data.items[0].statistics.viewCount +'</div><div class = title>'+ data2.items[0].snippet.title+'</div></div></div>');} 
    });
});
</script>
```

1 script = 1 video. There will be a bunch of these inside my body.

---

#### Solved

**Figured it out by making a timeout for the function.**

**Edit: Ok apparently, that litreally also requires that you put spacing between the `<script>` tag and the beginning of `setTimeout()`, like this (Jquery is a funny language???):**

```
<script>

    setTimeout(function() {
         // Also I'm not sure if you'll need the .get()
        var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();
        $('div#videocontainer').html(videos);
    }, 2000)
</script>
```

Comment: Is that script placed on `<head>`?

Comment: no, it is just place straight into the body (When i am done testing i am of course gonna link to a .js file instead). Why, is it an issue?

Comment: I guess the videos don't exist (loaded in via AJAX) until after document.ready has executed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script with "$.getJSON" is before the other script on the page.

Then try modifying your code to this:

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
         // Also I'm not sure if you'll need the .get()
        var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();
        $('div#videocontainer').html('<div>' + videos + '</div>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: interesting, it creates an empty div, with nothing inside

Comment: But the function works, just not with "$('document').ready". It's really weird

Comment: Seems like a race condition issue. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so of course i first figure it out myself just after posting on stackoverflow when i've been on google for the past 2 days.
Apparently, setting a timeout for the function made it work, like this:

```
<script>

    setTimeout(function() {
         // Also I'm not sure if you'll need the .get()
        var videos = $('div.videoframe').get();
        $('div#videocontainer').html(videos);
    }, 2000)
</script>
```

Thank you anyways guys :)